# Trying to import a CSV file with double delimiters + carriage return

Tags: csv, import, sas, delimiter

I'm trying to import a CSV dataset using (the wizard in) SAS Enterprise Guide. It provides me with 2 options:
1) Text format as delimited fields or
2) Fixed columns

However, I have a dataset which consists of data with 2 delimiters(text between " and ,), and also a carriage return after each line of data. This means I can't make use of the wizard. However, due to the nature of the formats (double delimiter + carriage return), I'm wondering how to read this using 'regular' code.

Please find an example file (which I would like to import) here: https://www.briandunning.com/sample-data/us-500.zip.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is likely that the import wizard doesn't figure out that the end of line symbol is a single carriage return.
I'm not sure what you mean by "double delimiter". From what I can see in your example CSV, there is just a simple comma delimiter and values are enclosed in double quotes in order to mask commas in the values.

Based your sample CSV, this code imports it successfully:

```
data want;
length first_name $20
       last_name $20
       company_name $30
       address $50
       city $20
       county $20
       state $2
       zip $10
       phone1 $20
       phone2 $20
       email $100
       web $100
             ;
infile 'path-to-file\us-500.csv' dsd delimiter=',' termstr=cr missover firstobs=2;
input first_name $
      last_name $
      company_name $
      address $
      city $
      county $
      state $
      zip $
      phone1 $
      phone2 $
      email $
      web $;
run;
```

The key here is the `termstr=cr` option which tells the `infile` statement that the termination symbol is a carriage return. The `dsd` option states that values are enclosed in double quotes and that when a delimiter is found in between double quotes, it is to be treated as a character.

Of course you can play around with those length statements to best suit your actual data.

Comment: One question though... it isn't possible to import the file using the wizard in Enterprise Guide? That is, with these kind of files you always have to code yourself?

Comment: @WouterHupkes I think It is possible to import them using the GUI but you have to pick the correct specifications, i.e. file type and then choose CSV. What did the GUI provide when you ran it? Did it incorrectly?

Comment: @Reeza I tried the GUI in EG before doing it with code. I played around with a bunch of options including setting the encoding manually and, no matter what, I couldn't get EG to properly detect the end of line.

Comment: @Reeza No, unfortunately it doesn't work; you can choose between "Delimited fields" and "Fixed columns". It doesn't process the 'enter' correctly.